# What are some good UX books?

Tags: user-interface

I am interesting in creating a better User Experience (UX).  There are a lot of books out there, what are some that would be useful to a software engineer?

Comment: This should probably be Community Wiki (edit post and check the little box to the bottom right)

Comment: Many folks call this HCI.  Perhaps you should use fewer acronyms as part of creating a better user experience?

Comment: @S. Lott: I've seen lots of names for this. Usability. User Experience/UX. Human-Computer Interaction/HCI. User interface design. I'm not even sure if there's any differences between these topics. It is annoying.

Comment: This can probably be moved to http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My favorites:

- [User Interface Design for Programmers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1893115941) by Joel Spolsky. A good first book for programmers. Phrases that will stick in your mind and affect your design, like "People can't control the mouse."
- [About Face: The Essentials of Interaction Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470084111) by Alan Cooper et al. Desktop-centric. Excellent.
- [Don't Make Me Think](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321344758) by Steve Krug. Web-centric. Short, easy read, good ideas, some remarks on usability testing.
- [Designing Interfaces: Patterns for Effective Interaction Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596008031) by Jennifer Tidwell
- [The Elements of Friendly Software Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0782115381) by Paul Heckel (out of print, pre-GUI, still some good principles, like "Avoid frustrating the user")
- [Designing Visual Interfaces: Communication Oriented Techniques](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0133033899) by Kevin Mullet and Darell Sano. Out-of-print, and out-of-date graphics, but still excellent. Good chapter on icons.
- [The Essential Guide to User Interface Design: An Introduction to GUI Design Principles and Techniques](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470053429) by Wilbert Galitz. Focuses on usage of low-level controls. Good chapter on communicating with the user.

At some point in your career, you may enjoy this wonderful book that draws parallels across multiple fields of design. (For example, the "confirmation" technique occurs both in software design and nuclear launch control.)

- [Universal Principles of Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1592530079) by William Lidwell

Comment: Universal Principles of Design is great. It was a suggested book for my software usability course, and the only book for the course I kept (the primary text was awful and no where near as helpful as it was).

Comment: I actually have Universal Principals of Design and love it.  I am hoping to find more of a book for programmers right now though.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

[The Design of Everyday Things](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0385267746) by Don Norman.

Answer (score 3):

it's specific to Web UX, but Steve Krug's [Don't Make me Think](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Dont-Make-Me-Think-Usability/dp/0321344758) is really interesting (and short, which always helps!).  And to be fair, some of it translates to non-web apps too.

As well as giving you advice on the design of the UX, it talks about [usability testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usability_testing), which is something I think a lot more apps should do.  (Websites too, but most of them do it already).

Comment: I found `Don't Make Me Think` really interesting and its not too long - the sort of tech book you could actually read cover to cover on a few bus trips and actually get something out of it.

Comment: This book is actually in the bibliography for the Spolsky book recommended by @Andy in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would also recommend [The Humane Interface: New Directions for Designing Interactive Systems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201379376) by Jef Raskin. Has some really inspiring ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Look up "[The Design of Every day things](http://mitpress.mit.edu/catalog/item/default.asp?tid=5393&ttype=2)", by Donald Norman. It was mandatory reading for the UI courses when I was in university.