# Java GUI: Getting started?

Tags: java, user-interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are some good UX books?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478401/what-are-some-good-ux-books)

I know a good bit of basic java, but I'm looking to learn some GUI design. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the official [Swing tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) is just fine to start with.